# Menu with Collapse BootStrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have a button in BootStrap.  I use "collapse" in a menu and each of those buttons when I push this to collapse this appear with any problem.

But when I push another button with this active appear down on the other.

How change this action? When I push any button this hide this but with the same animation like collapse do it.

Here is the code, when you try it you'll understand me:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#content0a">1<strong class="caret"></strong></a></li>
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#content1a">2<strong class="caret"></strong></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clearfix"><p>content more</p></div>
<div id="content0a" class="collapse">
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="thumbnail bs-example bullet0a">
        <div class="media">
            <div class="">
                <ul><li> Content...1 </li></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="content1a" class="collapse">
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="thumbnail bs-example bullet0a">
        <div class="media">
            <div class="">
                <ul><li> Content...2 </li></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If Content...1 is showing when you click on the 2 link do you want the Content...1 to disappear when Content...2 shows up?

Comment: Hello Trevor thanks for help me.

If the content 1 is active and i push the button #2 . The content 1 is desapear a instant like a dropdown in a bootstrap but with the same animation en a collapse

Comment: Hello Trevor i have a problem again with this nav-pills 

I insert a slider with special animation but this use a jQuery v1.9.0.

And my html use a jQuery v1.9.1 and When i remove this jQuery v1.9.1.

The animacion of the slider run perfectly.

but the nav-pills do not work. When i push the button reveal content ok but when push the other the last still here and no disappear . 

Appear like started the problem when you help me.

Can you help me please? if this necessary put a link of this problem. 

Please is urgen. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.nav-pills a').click(function(){
               $('.in').not($(this).data('target')).height(0);
               $('.in').not($(this).data('target')).removeClass('in');
           });
       });
   </script>
```

You can also try this. (which gives more of a collapse animation)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.nav-pills a').click(function(){
            $('.in').not($(this).data('target')).collapse('hide');
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can add it to the bottom of your page right before the `</body>` tag or add it to your existing javascript file.

Try that and let me know if it's close to what you want.

Comment: Yes if you like but i don't know how but i like share my work by link private and see how is looks like if you want. because still in development now.

Comment: Hello Trevor i have a problem again with this nav-pills 

I insert a slider with special animation but this use a jQuery v1.9.0.

And my html use a jQuery v1.9.1 and When i remove this jQuery v1.9.1.

The animacion of the slider run perfectly.

but the nav-pills do not work. When i push the button reveal content ok but when push the other the last still here and no disappear . 

Appear like started the problem when you help me.

Can you help me please? if this necessary put a link of this problem. 

Please is urgen. Regards

Comment: I just tried it in jQuery v1.9.0. and it worked for me.  http://bootply.com/88355  Are you sure your bootstrap files are still loaded?  You can send a link if you would like, I can take a look.. There are a couple things I could check but after that I don't know how much I can help.